# Laravel retrieve id from URL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I would like to retrieve an id from a Laravel URL.
I've tried this:

`$request->route('id');`

But it would tell me that $request is undefined.

The url I am using is:

`http://192.168.1.14/public/tasks/create?id=1`

I've got a sidebar and within that I've got an if statement.

```
@if((request()->is('projects/1')) || (request()->is('tasks/create')))
    <a href="{{ route('tasks.create') }}?id={{ $project->id }}">
@endif
```

I've hid the unnecessary code, but the second parameter is used for highlighting what page I am on in the sidebar. And the first for showing the create task option when I am on a project page.

Now, the if statement causes that its hidden ( so I can't see the error ( the error would say that there is no id but its true because it only receives the id by being on a project page with an id ))

Now, the task form on the page itself has a hidden input field with `project_id` so I can bind the task to the project.

Inside the value I have the `$request->route('id')` but it gives me an error that request is undefined.

Now I ask, how do I retrieve the id from the url, or else, can I retrieve the id another way? All the project and task blade files extend the `project.index` and the `project.index` extends the `layouts.blade` so its a layout within a layout.

Also, can I change the `(request()->is('projects/1'))` to something else so whatever project page I am on, the statement is true? For example 'projects/{project}'

Thanks for any help

Comment: use $request->get('id'); in case you are in a controller and if you are in a blade file use request()->get('id) it will work like a charm, BTW welcome to Stack, hope you feel home here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way to do this is 
You don't need to write 'create'

```
{{ app('request')->input('id') }}
```

or

```
{{ request()->get('id') }}
```

IF you are not sure how it works just 
store in a variable and print it on view to cross-verify like this.

```
<?php 
$id = app('request')->input('id');
//or
$id = request()->get('id');
?>
```

You can always check all request URL parameters like this.

```
$request = request();
print_r($request);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, the second suggestion worked like a charm. I was also wondering if you would be able to help with the latter issue?

Comment: would you be able to help with the issue in the post? The one about ```(request()->is('projects/1'))``` ?

Answer (score 0):

Create Route for getting id from url 
Example:

Route::name('subscriptions.store')->post('/subscriptions/store/{id}', 'CreateSubscriptionController');